# How to count all items inside all objects inside array

Tags: javascript

I need to make a count of all of the item inside of the array, this is my data model:

```
[
  {
    treats: [
      {
        id: "1",
        name: "treat 1",
        variants: ["one", "two", "three"],
        all_vars: false
      },
      {
        id: "2",
        name: "treat 2",
        variants: ["one", "two", "three"],
        all_vars: true
      },
      {
        id: "3",
        name: "treat 3",
        variants: ["one", "two", "three"],
        all_vars: true
      }
    ],
    packs: [
      {
        id: "1",
        name: "pack 1"
      },
      {
        id: "2",
        name: "pack 2"
      },
      {
        id: "3",
        name: "pack 3"
      }
    ],
    membs: [
      {
        id: "1",
        name: "mem 1"
      },
      {
        id: "2",
        name: "mem 2"
      },
      {
        id: "3",
        name: "mem 3"
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

What I want to accomplish is to get a sum of all of the objects PLUS if `all_vars` is `false` on treats, then add to the count the `variants` too, if the `all_vars` is true, then just count as 1.

The response I'm trying to get here is:

```
treats: 6
packs: 3
membs: 3
-----------
Total: 12
```

Is there a simple way to sum the count of everything?

Comment: Pleas show us your attempt!

Comment: @Yousaf you have to look at the variants, the first of which is set to false.  What I'm hung up on is "simple way."  There's a way, but what do you mean by simple?  Look through all of the objects one at a time, and if "all_vars" is true (or missing), add 'em up.  It's unclear what part of this you're unclear about.

Comment: What have you tried? part of your question sounds like how to get the length of an array, which is not something you should ask Stackoverflow for. If you are having specific trouble with getting the length of an array you should post your code you're having trouble with. The other one you could filter, `treats.filter({all_vars} => !!all_vars).length`

Answer (score 1):

One was is to jus a `reduce()` to count all those values, then inside the reduce callback, if the key is `treats`, use another reducer to add the variants.length if `all_vars` is true, otherwise, just add `0`.

```js
const data = {treats: [{id: "1", name: "treat 1", variants: ["one", "two", "three"], all_vars: false }, {id: "2", name: "treat 2", variants: ["one", "two", "three"], all_vars: true }, {id: "3", name: "treat 3", variants: ["one", "two", "three"], all_vars: true } ], packs: [{id: "1", name: "pack 1" }, {id: "2", name: "pack 2" }, {id: "3", name: "pack 3" } ], membs: [{id: "1", name: "mem 1" }, {id: "2", name: "mem 2" }, {id: "3", name: "mem 3" } ] };
  
const result = Object.keys(data).reduce((p, c) => ({
    ...p,
    [c]: (c === 'treats')
        ? data[c].reduce((p, c) => p + ((c.all_vars) ? 0 : c.variants.length), data[c].length)
        : data[c].length
}), {});

console.log(result);
```

This will output:

```json
{
  "treats": 6,
  "packs": 3,
  "membs": 3
}
```